# How to fix "upstream prematurely closed"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm setting up my server in order to avoid "upstream prematurely closed" error 502 that I get randomly on client calls. My Rest API Python/Flask is hosted on AWS on an Nginx/Uwsgi and I have 200 concurrents users maximum.

On the error log I get this message:

> 1180 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xx.xx.xx, server: _, request: "POST /API/sendmessage HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///opt/python/log/uwsgi.sock:", host: "XXX.XXXX-prod.com"

And on access.log I get the 502:

> "POST /API/sendmessage HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"

I already try an Apache configuration on AWS and it was worst! This is my current configuration:

Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.6
Type d'instance EC2 : c5.large

I share some config of my setup file:

```
  exec /opt/python/run/venv/bin/uwsgi \
     --socket=/opt/python/log/uwsgi.sock \
     --chdir=/opt/python/current/app \
     --module=wsgi:application \
     --pidfile=/opt/python/run/uwsgi-master.pid \
     --processes=4 \
     --threads=1 \
     --master \
     --uid=wsgi  \
     --gid=wsgi \
     --harakiri=300 \
     --max-requests=5000 \
     --vacuum \
     --die-on-term \
     --venv=/opt/python/run/venv \
     --chmod-socket=666
```

I try multiple things: change processes, thread, remove master, "die on term", but I'm really stuck. I think I have read all articles linked to this subject on Stack Overflow and on Google.

Comment: and what do you have in code ? Especially in `/API/sendmessage` ?

Comment: Thx Furas, I have really basic things and this error occured randomly on all my functions, not specially on this one